# How to trigger Angular 2 form submit from component?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

Basically, I have

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(f.form)" #formElement>
    ...
    <button class="btn btn-primary" #saveButton>Save</button>
</form>
```

I want to be able to trigger `submit()` from the component.
I've tried `@viewChild('formElement')` and `renderer.invokeElementMethod` to trigger `click()`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[NgForm](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm) has property `ngSubmit` which is [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter). So doing `emit()` on this property from the component will trigger a submit.

Also you need to use your `f` variable instead of `formElement` because `f` is referencing to `ngForm`.

```
@ViewChild('f') form: NgForm;

form.ngSubmit.emit();
```

Comment: all this time, i was trying to do that but I assigned it to the wrong template variable. :(. I have opt for a workaround using (change) instead of ngSubmit and let the client of the component checks for invalid, though. Anyways, thanks heaps. This answered the question I've posted so I accepted your answer.

Comment: Hi, I am in a similar situation where i have form in one component, and submit button is in it's parent's parent component. I tried viewChild. It is not working. Here is the link to stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-trigger-reactve-form-submission-from-parent-component

Comment: @Shrinivas In your case you cannot access the form with `ViewChild` from first and second level as the form is in a different component (level three). What you want to do is to have in second level `@ViewChild(LevelThreeComponent) lvlThreeCmpt: LevelThreeComponent;` and then call the method of the level three component upon level two submit - `lvlThreeCmpt.onNgSubmit()`. Same goes for level one - you need to access level two and then level three. The thing is it becomes very complex. Better way is to have a service and have the submit there.

Answer (score 5):

I was trying that `ngSubmit.emit()` approach to update the validation state of the form fields from component, now this can be done with:

```js
this.formGroup.markAllAsTouched();
```