# Submit a form from a button outside of the form in Angular

Tags: angular

How can I submit a form in Angular (2+) programmatically from a button which resides outside of the form?
This should be through a click event which invokes a function in an Angular component?

Comment: can a (click)="function()" not be used in the button to call the same function the form submitting uses?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag
hope it will help

Comment: I like this method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47408404/how-to-trigger-angular-2-form-submit-from-component

Comment: updated answer h

Answer (score 2):

I use the method shown here (from: [How to trigger Angular 2 form submit from component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47408404/how-to-trigger-angular-2-form-submit-from-component))

> NgForm has property ngSubmit which is EventEmitter. So doing emit() on
>   this property from the component will trigger a submit.
>
> Also you need to use your f variable instead of formElement because f
>   is referencing to ngForm.
>
> @ViewChild('f') form: NgForm;
>
> form.ngSubmit.emit();