# How to Submit an Angular reactive form programmatically?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

How can I submit a reactive form programmatically or how to detect the button which is clicked? I have 2 buttons to submit the same form and for each button click, I want to take different actions apart from submitting.

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)" [formGroup]="patientInfoForm">
.
.
.

            <button id="add" type="submit" >Add Patient & Continue</button>
            <button id="addngo" type="submit" >Add Patient</button>



</form>
```

Comment: Try the solution mentioned here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47408404/how-to-trigger-angular-2-form-submit-from-component

Comment: On both click you want to submit form?

Comment: Why don't you use type="button" and (click)="addFunction" and addngoFunction? In addFunction and addngoFunction you can call onSubmit() and access the form data by this.patientInfoForm.getRawValue() and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the `(ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)"` you'd have a method in your component TS file. It would look something like this:

**Component TS file**

```ts
addPatientAndContinue() {
    var formValue = this.patientInfoForm.value;
    // Submit the form data via a service (or HttpClient)
    // "Continue"
}

addPatient() {
    var formValue = this.patientInfoForm.value;
    // Submit the form data via a service (or HttpClient)
}
```

Then you would bind the `click` event of your buttons to the appropriate methods:

```ts
<button id="add" (click)="addPatientAndContinue()">Add Patient & Continue</button>
<button id="addngo" (click)="addPatient()">Add Patient</button>
```

Notice the `(click)` attribute on each button.

Comment: That's was a good idea. I don't know why I didn't try it :-) I was thinking there is something special happening onsubmit event.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ngNoForm with your form to remove ngForm handling and to add plain javascript handler.

you can use your code as follows:

Html file.

```
  <form ngNoForm
    [formGroup]="patientInfoForm"
    [action]='actionLink'
    method='POST'
    #patientInfoForm>
     <input name='Email' type='hidden' [value]='currentUserEmail'>
  </form>
```

Ts File.

```
  @ViewChild('patientInfoForm') patientInfoFormElement;

  public currentUserEmail: string = '';
  public patientInfoForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    Email: ''
  });


  //Submit form programmatically
  public patientInfoFormSubmitMethod(): void {
      this.patientInfoFormElement.nativeElement.submit();
  }
```